# Manually installing ia32-libs-multiarch on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Tags: software-installation

I manually downloaded ia32-libs-multiarch from packages.ubuntu.com and the version should be compatible with the 64bit 12.10.

From terminal, I get a 'package has no installation candidate. After several manual attempts with dpkg, I tried manually installing ia32-libs from [HERE](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ia32-libs), but failed.

What is the correct way to install ia32-libs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue,  just posting my findings to help anyone else.

I ran

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7-multilib
```

And it installed the `ia32-libs` from here I assume, suddenly works. I needed it to run XAMPP on Ubuntu 12.10 - May help someone!

Comment: Installing `gcc-4.6-multilib` works on 12.04 (which has no `gcc-4.7-multilib` package.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, did you try installing Skype before installing the libs? I've seen a few reports that there's no need to manually install ia32-libs on Quantal (ie - 32bit applications install just fine), though I haven't confirmed that myself. If you haven't, try that first. If you have, then continue on (and, since you're new, it'd be good to read on, anyway).

You don't need to download packages from packages.ubuntu.com in order to install them. That site is really only there for documentation and reference purposes.

All you need to do is open up terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

It'll prompt you for your password. Put it in, and let it do its thing. Once it's done, you should be able to install Skype without issue.

Comment: I obviously tried that before posting here. Can you please answer my question? How do you install something that has .postinst extension?

Comment: I did answer your question, read the rest of my answer. The .postinst extension is not an installable file, it's the extension for the post install script, which is designed to be run after an installation. If you're trying to run the .postinst file, then you're using the wrong file to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

Download the deb package either from [Ubuntu updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/raring/universe/base/ia32-libs-multiarch) or [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/ia32-libs/download) and install manually using `dpkg`.