# Teamviewer Not Correctly Installed

Tags: teamviewer

I installed (partially) TeamViewer but the installation did not complete because dependency errors. Teamviewer depends on ia32-libs which depends on ia32-libs-i386. The dependency tree can get quite long.

I tried running `sudo apt-get install -f` to no avail. Please if anyone has tips on installation help me.

As suggested the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` is

More problems to get a complete view of this problem. I tried this `dpkg --add-architecture i386` but dpkg says

> dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture

so might the problem be with dpkg?

[image]

Comment: Could you post what does ``sudo apt-get install -f`` exactly say at the moment?

Comment: @Vadi I edited it see above

Comment: as you can see I enter the command and see that. I remove teamviewer and then try and re-install. Its a cycle :(

Comment: Make sure you need the 32 bit version. I has similar problems and tracked it back to running the 32 bit instead of the 64 bit version.

Comment: I need 64bit but I can't find them

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`, `apt-cache depends teamviewer` and `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: @Braiam http://paste.ubuntu.com/6097626/ 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6097639/
the last one gave an output of done

Comment: possible duplicated [Install Teamviewer using a 64-bits system but I get lib32asound2 dependency error](http://askubuntu.com/a/363083)

Answer (score 0):

Do what it says - type `Y`. Then download the 64bit .deb from https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx, double-click on that and install that - it'll work.

Comment: I tried that. The one I have is the 64 bit version. I have tried everything you have asked.

Comment: What is the mentioned dependency tree, then? You haven't posted part of the output and only what you see when you have to remove the package due to incomplete dependencies.

Comment: here are the dependencies. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6087054/

Comment: Try the accepted answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/216845/manually-installing-ia32-libs-multiarch-on-ubuntu-12-10-64bit

Comment: Nope no help there. I tried installing the said package for 12.04 but it did not work.

Comment: At this point it would be really helpful to know your Ubuntu version. In your pastebin you mentioned ia32-libs-multiarch - which is only available for 13.04...

Is there a reason you are trying ``sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch:i386``? It should be ``sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch``.

Comment: I tried all the above suggestions man to no avail :(

Comment: Okay, but that adds nothing to conversation. I asked you what Ubuntu version you are on, and if ``sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`` failed, the output of what happened when you did that.

Otherwise, we've got nowhere to go here without you adding more.

Comment: I am 12.04.3 I get numerous other dependencies.See the http://paste.ubuntu.com/6094454/

Comment: Then install https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ia32-libs-multiarch only.

Comment: Here is what I get when I try to install the said package. http://i.stack.imgur.com/DzrpW.png

Comment: I'm dubious that you are on 12.04.3 or that your software sources are setup correctly.

Go to the software sources, enable (main), (universe), (restricted) and (multiverse) at minimum.

Comment: I am moving this to chat the comments are getting unwieldy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10573/discussion-between-mojo706-and-vadi)