# Installed Teamviewer using a 64-bit system, but I get a dependency error

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, teamviewer

I was trying to install Teamviewer, but I was getting a dependency error. I tried to install the required packages, but with no luck.

I'm getting this error:

```
Unpacking teamviewer (from teamviewer_linux_x64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:
 teamviewer depends on lib32asound2; however:
  Package lib32asound2 is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on lib32z1; however:
  Package lib32z1 is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing teamviewer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Getting

```
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

Package lib32asound2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lib32asound2' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

I can't even get to the

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

If I force installation

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -i teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

Although it's "Setting up Temviewer" it gives me this:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Install the "32-Bit / 64-Bit Multiarch" version. It worked on my system flawlessly. Do not install the 64bit only version. - http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx

Comment: all methods are useless to me. finally I downloaded this file from official website: https://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.tar.xz  then unzip it, run it, done!   (this version is run in the wine environment)

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 298, accepted):

The problem is that the `teamviewer_linux_x64.deb`, the package that was aimed to 64-bit systems, uses a obsolete package that tried to achieve multiarch previously in Debian based systems called `ia64-libs`. Although, that package scheme changed and now Teamviewer distribute the native build for both i386 and amd64 architecture, as they don't need anymore multiarch.

Simply downloading the [appropriated package for Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) and installing it using your favorite method, should be enough. This package also installs a repository, so it should also automatically upgrade itself when you upgrade your system.

Comment: I've tried Gdebi method, but it didn't helped.
I'm getting: *Dependency is not satisfiable: lib32asound2*

Comment: @SlavaFominII install 32-bit instead

Comment: what does :i386 mean? I'm on x64, should I use :i386?

Comment: @Alex yes. this answer is only applicable to 64-bit systems

Comment: That's funny, doesn't i386 mean 32, whereas ia64 (or something) means 64-bit?

Comment: @Alex http://askubuntu.com/q/54296/169736

Comment: **i386 refers to the 32-bit edition of windows and amd64 (or x86_64) refers to the 64-bit edition.** -- this is what I said. Whereas you said that i386 was 64-bit

Comment: @Alex you don't understand. They doesn't have a 64-bit binary for TeamViewer, so they were relying in ia32-libs and now multiarch so their 32-bit binaries works in 64-bits systems.

Comment: @Braiam Any [suggestions for signing key?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35449973/2404470) please?

Comment: TeamViewer has given out a new release for Ubuntu in their site and 
sudo apt-get -f install ./teamviewer_13.1.3026_amd64.deb

would install it without any further steps required.

Answer (score 10):

All I had to do to amend this problem was do `dpkg --force-all -i *.deb` to install that package. Note that the only dependency it couldn't resolve was libpng12-0, so after forcing the install it has no images in the interface but it is still runnable. The other solutions did not solve the problem for me. I'm hoping the Teamviewer developers will get to this soon.

Comment: I do the same conclusion as you. Did you contacted the teamviewer support service ? Did you obtained any response from them ? Have you got a solution ?

Comment: I never contacted them, just because in my experience no company wants to support Linux so I always just get my help here.

Comment: Ok thank you for your reactivity. We can't same the same about the TeamViewer team, these arch and missing dependency issues are there in each new major version.  They don't care about us, its so ridiculous. Its just about build a clean package for their software... And we pay for that..

Comment: My skills are nowhere near good enough to do it myself, but I suppose what you can do is remove the dependency for the libpng package that doesn't work from the list of dependencies for TeamViewer, then add a different package that has full PNG support and then program that one in manually. I don't know if this is possible or easy to do, but if we take it upon ourselves to make a different package work for this program we can make it work I think.

Answer (score 2):

To install on Ubuntu 20.04 x64, from https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-teamviewer-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdebi-core wget
wget -O ~/teamviewer.deb "https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb"
sudo gdebi ~/teamviewer.deb 
teamviewer
```

Answer (score 1):

With Teamviewer 15 on Ubuntu 20.04:

Download and install with

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_15.16.8_amd64.deb   # adapt to your downloaded file name
```

This will show dependency errors, but all you have to do to fix them is

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all dependency libraries for i386 (this might work with 64 too) as described above.
For the missing libpng12 library just go to: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/i386/libpng12-0/download
and install with

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_i386.deb
```

it has no dependencies which wouldn't be resolved by current environemnt:

dep: libc6 (>= 2.14), zlib1g    (>= 1:1.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

### TeamViewer for Linux

TeamViewer 14.0 is out for Linux and it's no longer [based on Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125153/team-viewer-on-ubuntu-is-it-running-through-wine/125167#125167). TeamViewer 14.0 features native 64-bit support and a Qt front-end. .deb packages for TeamViewer 14.0 for Linux are available from the [official TeamViewer website](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/).

- [TeamViewer 64-bit](https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb)
- [TeamViewer 32-bit](https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_i386.deb)

On Ubuntu 17.10 some features of TeamViewer require Xorg to be selected instead of the default Wayland at the login screen. In Wayland only outgoing remote control and incoming file transfer are supported. If you need incoming remote control you have to login to classic Xorg. In order to enter an X session from the GDM login screen select **Ubuntu on Xorg**.

Comment: `TeamViewer 13+14` Linux version sadly also „feature“ [a missing meeting button...](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/Update-14-1-3399-TeamViewer-14/m-p/46527/highlight/true#M2645)