# Teamviewer cannot install on 13.10 - no teamviewerd

Tags: teamviewer

I tried to install Teamviewer 8 on Xubuntu 13.10 after the first problems I tries this solution:

> [Installed Teamviewer using a 64-bits system, but I get a dependency error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/teamviewer-dependends-of-lib32asound2)

But that doesen't work either,  after trying (as root)

```
apt-get install libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libasound2:i386 libfreetype6:i386 zlib1g:i386 libsm6:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386
wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
```

I get these messages:

```
Vorbereitung zum Ersetzen von teamviewer 8.0.20931 (durch teamviewer_linux.deb) ...
initctl: Unbekannter Auftrag: teamviewerd
Ersatz für teamviewer wird entpackt ...
teamviewer (8.0.20931) wird eingerichtet ...
initctl: Unbekannter Auftrag: teamviewerd
```

I guess in english:

```
initctl: unknown task: teamviewerd
```

---

After some apt-get upgrades during the last days, this seem to be fixed by now:

```
sudo service teamviewerd start
```

starts the deamon now and I can start teamviewer after that.

The strange thing is, that I have to start the teamviewerd now by hand each time I want to use Teamviewer (Before the upgrade Teamviewer could start right away)

Comment: how are you trying it ? normal or root user ?

Comment: I installed it as root

Comment: as a newbie i tried : sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 the result was: Depends: bash (>= 3.0) , libc6-i386 (>= 2.4), lib32asound2, lib32z1, libxext6, ia32-libs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some apt-get upgrades during the last days, this seem to be fixed by now:

```
sudo service teamviewerd start
```

starts the deamon now and I can start teamviewer after that

Answer (score -2):

[Here's the *actual* solution](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx#multiarch)

Here's what that page says:

```
Notes to Multiarch:
On newer 64-bit DEB-systems with Multiarch-support (Debian 7) teamviewer_linux_x64.deb cannot be installed because the package ia32-libs is not available anymore on these systems. In this case you can use teamviewer_linux.deb instead.

In case you get the error “wrong architecture i386” you have to execute the following command lines:

dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
For further information: http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO
```

Basically, what they're saying (without saying it) is that, even though tthere's a package called "64 bit", it's not. So you have to install the 32bit one.

Comment: He installed the correct package, as said in his question (which is linked to my answer), the problem was that teamviewer service/daemon do not starts.

Answer (score -2):

On newer 64-bit DEB-systems with Multiarch-support (Debian 7) teamviewer_linux_x64.deb cannot be installed because the package ia32-libs is not available anymore on these systems. In this case you can use teamviewer_linux.deb instead.

Download the Teamviewer on the given below links and double clicks it, in order to run the setup with Ubuntu software center.

http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb

Comment: He installed the correct package, as said in his question (which is linked to my answer), the problem was that teamviewer service/daemon do not starts.