# How to remotely control my Android?

Tags: android, rdp

I had a Windows OS earlier and could use TeamViewer to connect to my Samsung phone and execute actions.

However that was not only very slow but also very slow in response.

Is there any other way to sort of open a *RDP session* to the phone from my Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: Well, you could use TeamViewer from Linux, too.

Comment: Remmina is a RDP client, installed by default in ubuntu. But it assumes you have a RDP server on your phone.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/i-want-to-remotely-control-my-android-device-from-my-pc-without-rooting-it-is-t

Comment: https://apuppet.org is a self hosted and open source software to control Android phones remotely. It can be installed on Ubuntu 16.04 and above. No root required on the phone. The software is not RDP-based though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Droid VNC Server

Allows you to remote control your android within your computer.

**Note:** *Your phone must be ROOTED!*

**Note:** *Will not work on Tegra3 Devices*

#### On your android Phone:

- Install [Droid VNC Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&hl=en) from playstore.
- Open the app and click on **START**.
- It shows the IP-address and port number. Please note it down.

  [image]

#### On your Ubuntu PC:

- Install `xtightvncviewer` by running the below command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xtightvncviewer
  ```
- After installing `xtightvncviewer` run the below command to view your phone's screen:

  ```
  vncviewer xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
  ```

  `xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx` - already noted `ipaddress:port`

  [image]

### WebKey

Using this application you can control your phone from any browser.

**Note:** *Your phone must be ROOTED!*

#### On your android Phone:

- Install [WebKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webkey&feature=search_result) app from Play store.
- Open the WebKey app and select **start service**.
- Note down the https link generated.

  [image]
- On that same application, go to **settings->User settings->Click on Create new user** to create a new  user with login credentials.

  [image]

#### On your Ubuntu PC:

- Open any browser. I prefer Firefox. Then paste the noted link on the address bar. It display like `connection is not secure`. Trust the connection and allow it to load.
- After that a page will open and ask you to give the username and password. Login with the same username and password.

  [image]
- After loged into your account, you can view your phone and operate your android phone from there.

  [image]

### Team Viewer

**Note:** *Will not work on all Galaxy devices*

- Install [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/products/remotecontrol.aspx) on both Ubuntu PC and android  phone to control your phone from PC.
- [How to install Teamviewer on an 64 bit Ubuntu PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/install-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error).

Comment: Very cool! Webkey sounds scary - although I guess (or it should) it only allows traffic from the local LAN? I recommend installing AFWall+ firewall and block the proper ports when you don't want to use it. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall&hl=en

Comment: @AvinashRaj The same apps were proposed by kamil's answer before you. Why should one like you repeat other's answers?

Comment: @maythux he only specify the app name and don't mention to do after installing that app on android.I also explained it in detail and also i added an extra webkey app but he didn't  mention that.

Comment: webkey is excellent! fully working here til now, many thx! my screen is partially broken and this is the only way to not trash my phone...; Droid VNC Server will never start the server with this error "could not connect to ipc gui"; I think I will also install teamviewer just to have another alternative, thx again!

Answer (score 6):

A solution I found recently is `scrcpy` ([scrcpy github page](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)). It lets your pc connect to your phone and you can control your phone through it. It works through `adb` without any need to install an apk on your android phone beforehand. It streams your phone's screen to your pc, taking into account the rotation, and it allows to send clicks and touches with the mouse and write in text fields directly through your pc's keyboard, although you can only write ascii characters that way.

Since this only needs `adb`, it works as long as you achieve an `adb` connection with your phone, so that includes USB cable and Wifi connection for truly remote control. I don't know how you could do it over the network without being on the same LAN, though.

Answer (score 4):

If you would like something simple (i.e. Your phone's screen broke like me...) then you can use [AndroidScreencast](https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast). Take the jar from [here](https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast/releases) and make sure you have `adb` working properly then `java -jar androidscreencast-*.jar`. Lastly, connect your device through the usb and start the client.

Comment: Thanks for this method, but it works via USB slower than TeamViewer via WiFi + their server.

Comment: works but it is slow af.

Answer (score 3):

You can use VNC

1. On your android Phone install [Droid VNC Server](https://github.com/oNaiPs/droidVncServer/blob/master/bin/droid-VNC-server.apk)
2. On your Ubuntu PC you have to add a [Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/) VNC Connection. [In instance, watch this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7i8c91tUGJs).

   There are a [lot of apps similar to this](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/201720-remote-control-android-from-pc).

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) do the job as well.

Comment: Droid VNC server is no longer available.

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari check the github link
https://github.com/oNaiPs/droidVncServer/blob/master/bin/droid-VNC-server.apk

Answer (score 3):

You can use VMLite VNC Server

It's a combination of an Android app, desktop app plus VNC viewer app that will allow you to control an Android phone or tablet from a computer or another Android device!

**Features:**

- Control your Android phone or tablet from your computer or laptop!
- Works in a desktop program or web browser!
- Possible to project your phone onto a larger screen!
- Works on non-rooted devices as well as rooted!

**How to Setup VMLite VNC Server**

- [Install the desktop app](http://www.vmlite.com/vaac/#downloads) from developer’s site here. [Learn how to install](http://www.vmlite.com/vaac/#install_on_linux).  Hint: be sure to
  allow this app through your firewall.
- Install the Android app.
- Install a VNC viewer app of your choice.
- Run the VMLite VNC Server app.
- Run your VNC viewer app and enter the IP address information from
  your phone then click “Connect”.

[image]

[Official  and source for further information](http://www.androidtapp.com/vmlite-vnc-server/)

Comment: unfortunately it is not free :(

Answer (score 1):

[Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en) is what I use, maybe it's what you're looking for, maybe not. You don't need to install anything on the OS you're using, you don't need to create accounts, it's free.

Comment: do you believe the "screenshot" airdroid option could allow us to interact with the device? it shows the screen but we can only take a screenshot; but I need to interact with it as my phone touch screen is partially broken :)

Answer (score 0):

There also is [droidVNC-NG](https://github.com/bk138/droidVNC-NG) (which I authored). It does not require root and runs on Android 7+. It's open-source and available for free on Google Play and F-Droid. You can connect with any VNC viewer.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the open-source [androidVNC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.androidVNC). It is also [available](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=vnc&fdid=android.androidVNC) for installation from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/).

> See and control your computer's desktop from your phone, from anywhere.
>   androidVNC is the Open Source (GPL) remote desktop program for Android devices. Connects to most VNC servers: incl TightVNC, RealVNC on Win and Linux, x11vnc, and Apple Remote Desktop on OS/X.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The title reads "How to remotely control my Android" so this answer even though not detailed is correct!