# How to remotely display my Android on my PC?

Tags: android, screencast

There is a thing which is called miracast, it can mirror the display of the Android phone to another monitor, but my screen doesn't have this function, am I possible to do it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Take a look at Airdroid.

Comment: Is this topic still up? @JulianLai

Answer (score 7):

### [Scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/)

<s><sub>Scrcpy is an open source alternative that sounds promising, but I get across [this bug](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/294). I didn't want to use TeamViewer, LogMeIn or AirDroid.</sub></s>

This alternative also let you remotely use the phone from Ubuntu.

1. [Install adb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34702/how-do-i-set-up-android-adb): `sudo apt install adb`.
2. Install scrcpy (if you meet [the requirements](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy#requirements)): `brew install scrcpy` (yes, [brew](https://brew.sh/)) or `apt install scrcpy`.
3. [Enable adb debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#Enabling), the device should be listed on `adb devices`. Maybe you need to [move to PTP](https://askubuntu.com/a/632668/349837) and [a little more](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/70#issuecomment-373286323).

When you get the message the *Allow USB debugging? The computer's RSA key fingerprint is: [a fingerprint]* is possible to check it with following command (the public key might be in `~/.android` or `~/snap/scrcpy/current/.android/`):

```
cut -d" " -f1 adbkey.pub | openssl base64 -A -d -a | openssl md5 -c
```

Also, **`scrcpy --help`**:

- Tap **BACK**, **HOME** and **APP_SWITCH** with [these shortcuts](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/7#issuecomment-371772919).
- scrcpy 1.9+: <kbd>Ctrl + o</kbd> [turn device screen off](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-v1-9-mirror-screen-display-off/) (keep mirroring). Bidirectional shared clipboard.
- scrcpy 1.10+: [use it wirelessly](https://www.genymotion.com/blog/open-source-project-scrcpy-now-works-wirelessly/).
- scrcpy 1.12+: <kbd>Ctrl + r</kbd> rotate the screen.

The project is very active, keep track of [releases](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/releases) and update often.

If you like GUIs, try [guiscrcpy](https://guiscrcpy.github.io/) ([source](https://github.com/srevinsaju/guiscrcpy)), a scrcpy front-end written in Python `pip3 install --upgrade guiscrcpy --user`. Maybe some day will be the open source alternative to Microsoft's [Your Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/your-phone/9nmpj99vjbwv).

### [Screen Stream over HTTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.dvkr.screenstream&hl=en&rdid=info.dvkr.screenstream)

A nice [open source](https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream) alternative, also on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/info.dvkr.screenstream/).

[image: screenshot]

### [**LiveScreen**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.livescreenapp.free&rdid=com.livescreenapp.free)

Easy and no sign up crap. Just [install it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.livescreenapp.free&rdid=com.livescreenapp.free) and on the app switch screen sharing on:

[image: screenshot]

Then on your browser ([hopefully Firefox](https://youtu.be/ELCq63652ig), or [Brave](https://brave.com/)) pointing to your mobile's IP:

[image: screenshot]

### Furthermore

- [Nice related AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/420221/349837).
- [Waydroid](https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-on-desktops) or [Anbox](https://askubuntu.com/q/1033620/349837), both *a container-based approach to boot a full Android system on a regular GNU/Linux system*

Comment: Scrcpy works ...it works on amazon fire also

Answer (score 3):

You can use Teamviewer (sign-up needed)

1. download it for your computer [here](https://www.teamviewer.com/download/linux/).
2. download Teamviewer host for your phone [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.host.market)

you will get a secure connection between them and are able to control the screen and phone fully.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it easily with [Ashot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/). It's an open source project, programmed in Java, so you just download and run (assuming you have Android Studio already set up).

When you extract the folder, run `java -jar AShot-1.1.jar`. It will ask you for the Android SDK. Browse to it, and select your path (something like `/home/yourUserName/Android/Sdk/`). It should connect automatically and display the Android screen that is connected via USB. If you get an error in connection, copy the `adb` executable from `platform-tools/` to `tools/` and try again.

To copy:

```
cd Android/Sdk
cp platform-tools/adb tools/
```

It has a slight delay, so it's not good for streaming video, but good enough for presentations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Google Cast app for your Android phone you need [to download](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app&hl=en).

[Google Cast Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/reviews) for Chrome is discontinued because of [remotedesktop.google.com](https://remotedesktop.google.com).

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to do it without Chrome browser?

Comment: The Google Cast plugin in Chrome appears to be for sending rather than receiving?

Comment: Yes you need the app for sending

Comment: This plugin not supported anymore

Answer (score 0):

Screen Stream is another app that can do this. You install the app on your Android device, and then connect to it through wifi (or optionally 3G) from your PC using a normal webbrowser.

Internally, the app captures the screen and sends it as a MJPEG stream to the browser. It is not super-fast, so unsuitable for video, but it works well enough for showing other stuff.

The app is open source and available from [F-droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/info.dvkr.screenstream/) and the normal [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.dvkr.screenstream&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

WIRELESS OVER WIFI:

basic command from https://www.genymotion.com/blog/open-source-project-scrcpy-now-works-wirelessly/ (you can read more details and tips there):

```
# you need to have pc's adb and scrcpy working already thru usb cable on your android
# connect both the pc and your android in the same wifi
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.0.123:5555 #get the IP from your WIFI settings on your android
scrcpy

#to undo
adb usb
```