# How to install and run Anbox in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, anbox

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and I want to install [Anbox](https://anbox.io/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/anbox/)).

I am having trouble installing Anbox the way given in the current tutorials.

Comment: Anbox doesn't even support Artful. There is no PPA for Bionic. I spent too much time trying to make it work on Ubuntu 18.04 but kernel module just _didnt work._ Your best bet is to rebuild from sources..

Comment: @karel because the snap package only contains an installer script of several kilobytes.. the actual anbox container's size is about 400MB and it's downloaded on the first launch from a PPA. Edit: I see that you already mentioned that in [your answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/944245/810348)

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie. How do I rebuild from source?

Comment: you can follow the steps [from the original github repo](https://github.com/anbox/anbox#build-from-source), the build fails midway for me although there are reports of successful builds on bionic in the issues section.
@karel welcome

Comment: Check also [Waydroid](https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-on-desktops), _A container-based approach to boot a full Android system on a regular GNU/Linux system_

Comment: @PabloBianchi
Will it be possible to run playstore in linux using Waydroid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anbox is now available for Bionic 18.04+:

- [Official Website](https://anbox.io/)
- [GitHub sources](https://github.com/anbox/anbox)
- [Installation instructions](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/blob/master/docs/install.md)
- [Install guide](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install.html)

Installation on Ubuntu 18.04:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support
sudo apt install -y anbox-modules-dkms
sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
sudo modprobe binder_linux
sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox
```

Comment: for `snap` use command `sudo apt-get install snapd`

Answer (score 3):

There is now [an official snap](https://snapcraft.io/anbox) for Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.

```
sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox
```