# Help needed to access Audiobooks

Tags: audiobooks

Hi i use audible on my mobile devices - is there a way of listening to audible on ubuntu. i have 18.04.3 lts installed.
Ihave tried downloading audiobook downloader etc. but it will not launch. I cannot find any up to date info and also, audible web browser does not work in mozilla
Thanks

John

Comment: Do you mean Amazon Audible, then it does not work on Linux. https://audible-uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6069/kw/cloud

Answer (score 0):

You will have to emulate Android on your Ubuntu PC
Then install the Amazon Audible App

See : [How to install and run Anbox in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033620/how-to-install-and-run-anbox-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the audiobooks with a tool named [DumpMedia Audible Converter](https://www.dumpmedia.com/video-converter/) for Windows/MacOS. And then you can import your downloaded files on ubuntu. The converter can convert Audible AA/AAX audiobooks to MP3 so that you can play your audiobooks on many players.

Comment: Could you post more details?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, but there is a snap.

https://snapcraft.io/audible-for-linux

To install:

```
sudo snap install audible-for-linux
```