# Remote Control Desktop over Bluetooth

Tags: 13.10, android, bluetooth, remote-access

Is there a way to control my Ubuntu Desktop (13.10) remotely over Bluetooth, with my Android 4.4 device?

Answer (score 3):

[AnyRemote](http://anyremote.sourceforge.net/) works very nicely  for controlling applications - first install in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install anyremote ganyremote
```

Then you have install the client for the Android phone - download the `.apk` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/anyremote/files/anyremote-android-client/), put the file on your phone, and then open it and install it to the phone - you need to allow installation from 'Unknown Sources' in Security settings first.

There is documentation available [here](http://anyremote.sourceforge.net/docs.html) to help you set it up.

---

For controlling your desktop, something like VNC is very useful, but as that has already be mentioned, you may also want to try [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) - the android App for it can be found [here](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mobile.aspx).

To install for 32bit (works):

```
wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo gdebi install teamviewer_linux.deb
```

To install for 64bit (might work):

```
wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
sudo gdebi install teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

If you get an error with `lib32asound2` or some other dependency, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/363083/178596). If that does not work on 64bit, you should be able to install the 32bit version.

Comment: TeamViewers needs lib32asound2 which doesn't appear to be anywhere in the PPAs.

Comment: Work(ed) in my 13.10 - wait a bit...

Answer (score 1):

You can use VNC.

In your phone:

[click here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.androidVNC&hl=en) to install android-vnc-viewer

Write this on your terminal from Ubuntu Desktop

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

Comment: That's not bluetooth though. I want to be able to connect to my computer without using the network.

Comment: @JeroenBollen in bluetooth you can enable PAN networking and it should work

Comment: yeah it is not bluetooth, it uses network connection.

Comment: @NKN you mean network connection is enough. there is no need for internet

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to install VNC on the ubuntu. You can use the built-in VNC feature. Ubuntu’s remote desktop technology is based on the existing VNC standard. This means you can connect to a Ubuntu remote desktop using any VNC client. There are more than a few VNC clients around, so if you have a favorite on any platform you can use that to connect to Ubuntu already. (This answer is to complete @kamil 's answer.)

check this [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-remote-desktop-builtin-vnc-compatible-dead-easy/) for more info.