# How to install Teamviewer on 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, teamviewer

I tried to install Teamviewer 9 on Ubuntu 14.04, unsuccessfully.

I've downloaded the following extra(Raring) packages:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ia32-libs/ia32-libs-multiarch_20090808ubuntu36_i386.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ia32-libs/ia32-libs_20090808ubuntu36_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1_i386.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/lib32asound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx
```

But these errors were happened while I was installing the packages (I've also tried install with Ubuntu's Software Center, the same):

```
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb


Selecting previously unselected package ia32-libs.
(Reading database ... 254553 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ia32-libs_20090808ubuntu36_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ia32-libs (20090808ubuntu36) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ia32-libs-multiarch.
Preparing to unpack ia32-libs-multiarch_20090808ubuntu36_i386.deb ...
Unpacking ia32-libs-multiarch (20090808ubuntu36) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32asound2.
Preparing to unpack lib32asound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32asound2 (1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1) ...
dpkg: warning: downgrading libasound2:amd64 from 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7 to 1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1
Preparing to unpack libasound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libasound2:i386 (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
Unpacking libasound2:amd64 (1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1) over (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
Replaced by files in installed package libasound2-data (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
dpkg: warning: downgrading libasound2:i386 from 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7 to 1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1
Preparing to unpack libasound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libasound2:i386 (1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1) over (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
Replaced by files in installed package libasound2-data (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer.
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_linux_x64.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer (9.0.27891) ...
More than one copy of package libasound2:i386 has been unpacked
 in this run !  Only configuring it once.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ia32-libs-multiarch:
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on bluez-alsa; however:
  Package bluez-alsa:i386 is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on libgettextpo0; however:
  Package libgettextpo0 is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on gstreamer0.10-plugins-good; however:
  Package gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on gtk2-engines; however:
  Package gtk2-engines is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on gtk2-engines-murrine; however:
  Package gtk2-engines-murrine is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on gtk2-engines-pixbuf; however:
  Package gtk2-engines-pixbuf is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on gtk2-engines-oxygen; however:
  Package gtk2-engines-oxygen is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on ibus-gtk; however:
  Package ibus-gtk is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on libaio1; however:
  Package libaio1:i386 is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depen
dpkg: error processing package ia32-libs-multiarch (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libasound2:amd64:
 libasound2-data (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) breaks libasound2 (<< 1.0.27-4) and is installed.
  Version of libasound2:amd64 to be configured is 1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1.

dpkg: error processing package libasound2:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libasound2:i386:
 libasound2-data (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) breaks libasound2 (<< 1.0.27-4) and is installed.
  Version of libasound2:i386 to be configured is 1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1.

dpkg: error processing package libasound2:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ia32-libs:
 ia32-libs depends on ia32-libs-multiarch; however:
  Package ia32-libs-multiarch is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ia32-libs (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lib32asound2:
 lib32asound2 depends on libasound2 (= 1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package libasound2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lib32asound2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:
 teamviewer depends on lib32asound2; however:
  Package lib32asound2 is not configured yet.
 teamviewer depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package teamviewer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ia32-libs-multiarch
 libasound2:amd64
 libasound2:i386
 ia32-libs
 lib32asound2
 teamviewer
```

Do someone know how to install the Teamviewer on 14.04?

Comment: Why don't you use Ubuntu's Software Center to install TeamViewer (by double clicking the .deb)? The Software Center will automatically resolve and install the dependencies for you.

Comment: Sorry, I've forget to mention in the question. I've tried from that Ubuntu's Software Center too!

Comment: I had the same problem as you with 64-bit of team viewer, just try 32-bit and you will be fine.

Comment: @Braiam showed in [his answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/363083/34298): First, download the 32 bit version:

    `wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb` - 

First, install **gdebi**:

    `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386;
    sudo apt-get update;
    sudo apt-get install gdebi`

In the same directory you downloaded the **.deb** file just run:

    `sudo gdebi teamviewer_linux.deb`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 11.10, there is no longer an `ia32-libs` package. Because of this, older x64 packages (such as the x64 version distributed on their site) will no longer be able to install.

TeamViewer has since removed the x64-only download, and they only offer the i386 version.

To install TeamViewer now, it's as simple as visiting the [official download page](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/), clicking the "Download" button, and then running the downloaded `.deb` file.

If you want to use the terminal for this operation, that's still doable:

1. Grab the TeamViewer debfile:

   ```
    wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb
   ```
2. Install the downloaded DEB file:

   ```
    sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_i386.deb
   ```
3. If DPKG throws any errors, fix any dependency issues to make sure everything works fine:

   ```
    sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install
   ```

TeamViewer will now be ready for use and will be present in your menu.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right! Thank you. Otherwise, it is just a temporary solution. I'm looking forward to run the TV without Multiarch, and Mono/Wine, but natively on amd64!

Comment: Bad idea. TeamViewer 64bit was made for non-multiarch systems. In essence, it was the same product, requiring ia32-libs (which is gone). Teamviewer needs Wine/Mono as that is how the code is written. No way around it.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know a PPA, where I can get the latest upgrades automatically? If none, I'll create one, and mirror the official updates - I hope there'll no legal problems.

Comment: Sadly, no, I do not know a PPA. TeamViewer usually notifies you of updates, though.

Comment: Ok, then I'll try to create a "mirror" PPA.

Comment: in general, to avoid console stuff like dpkg - you can use gdebi - same, but with clicks :)

Comment: Downvote, why??

Comment: Too crazy. If there is a x64, why we have to install x86??? I installed 32bit version on 64bit Ubuntu.

Comment: @shgnInc Because of Multiarch. TeamViewer was written for 32bit, and the 32bit files has **no differences** from the 64bit file, save for a few dependencies.

Comment: I got some errors: http://pastebin.com/HeUyhAuh     it's 32bit version on ubuntu x64 14.04. Actually TreamViewer used to work months ago. But I had to upgrade to new version because on Win 8 PC it upgraded by itself. So Now it is not working at all. Just I can't install it

Comment: @Tosho That's not TeamViewer's fault. Another program is interfering/improperly configured. Please ask a new question using the "Ask Question" button in the top right corner of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have wine installed, just like the answer in the link provided by @B. Roland. Wine is needed, because TeamViewer uses some.dll libraries provided by wine.

Comment: I've already had [Wine(1.6)](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/wine1.6) installed. Your answer didn't help, sorry and thank you. Please test your answers first!

Comment: Have you tried installing the dependencies that always helps.             
  Package 'bluez-alsa:i386 is not installed.
  Package libgettextpo0 is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch depends on gstreamer0.10-plugins-good; however:
  Package gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 is not installed.
  Package gtk2-engines is not installed.
  Package gtk2-engines-murrine is not installed.
  Package gtk2-engines-pixbuf is not installed.
  Package gtk2-engines-oxygen is not installed.
  Package ibus-gtk is not installed.
  Package libaio1:i386 is not installed.'

Comment: wine is for "exe" files, teamviewer comes with preconfigured wine version, so - simply use 32 bit version