# Can't install Teamviewer due to libxtst6

Tags: dependencies, teamviewer

I cant seem to install Teamviewer 10, at the Software Center it says:

```
"Dependency is not satisfiable: lib32asound2"
```

Not really sure what to do there, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32asound2
```

but it said:

```
E: Unable to locate package lib32asound2
```

Comment: Can you try installing it using `apt-get`?

Comment: there's no `lib32asound2` package in 14.04LTS repos but in 12.04LTS

Comment: follow these suggestions http://askubuntu.com/questions/453157/how-to-install-teamviewer-on-14-04

Answer (score 0):

According to [this possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/installed-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error), you need to install the 32-bit version instead of the 64-bit. Read the first answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Teamviewer depends on some dll and therefore needs wine to work.

   `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`
2. Download teamviewer (32/64bit depends on wine settings).
3. Open terminal, navigate to the downloaded file.
4. Run (rename filename if needed)

   `sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb`

Comment: Cant even install wine, Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wine1.7
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.7'

Comment: try to install it via the software center (just search for wine)