# Cannot install Teamviewer_linux.deb package on linux 64bit

Tags: apt, dpkg, teamviewer

I wanted to install teamviewer on linux 64-bit system.

What I did was to download [teamviewer.deb file](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb) and install it as below:

```
sudo dpkg -i install teamviewer.deb
```

Then I wanted to correct dependency problem so I issued the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libasound2:i386 libfreetype6:i386 zlib1g:i386 libsm6:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386
```

I got the following error:

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I then tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Again I got the following error:

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Even I tried to install `gdebi`, but I got the above error again.

I emptied archives folder:

```
sudo apt-get clean  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Again I have problem installing my deb package. Is there anything I could do now to solve this problem?

---

**I've read the below article as well:**

[Installed Teamviewer using a 64-bits system, but I get a dependency error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/install-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error)

---

**EDIT:**

I found `libperl5.14:amd64` as a broken package. I used:

```
sudo apt-get remove libperl5.14:amd64
```

I got the following message:

```
E: Unable to locate package Broken
```

This is [my whole apt.log file](http://pastebin.com/z32fH3uz). I found a few more broken packages. I've done the same thing and got the same message.

---

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to install teamviewer_linux.deb via software center and I found repair button I clicked it and again I got the error below:

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

even after package removal and installing it via software center I got the error below:

```
Can not install 'libfreetype6:i386'
```

**EDIT 3:**

Can sources.list affect the process of installing deb packages? This is the only thing I'm suspicious of!

**EDIT 4:**

When after that I type `sudo apt-get install -f` I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded
```

**EDIT 5:**
Output of `sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb`:

```
dpkg: error processing package teamviewer (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
teamviewer
```

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? it works perfectly wehen you use the gdebi method.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, the problem is that I cannot even install gdebi? I get dependency error. Isn't that because of wrong sources.list or maybe this file lacks universe or main?

Comment: first you should  solve broken dependency problem I think, See here.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: What's with the 18 not upgraded? Any specific reason those haven't been upgraded?

Comment: Have no idea. I've upgraded them all. Now I have nothing to upgrade ;-)

Comment: @Bibi424 that is the most unhelpful link you could have picked.

Comment: @phpGeek please, **do not truncate the output** of the commands you run. Also please add the **complete output** of `sudo apt-get check` and `sudo dpkg -C`, and only keep the things that you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

it is answered here: [Installed Teamviewer using a 64-bits system, but I get a dependency error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/install-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error)

Comment: can you add error you getting to the Question?

Comment: put your **teamviever_linux.deb** file to home directory and try once again from 4th command.

Comment: Is it present in home. Pls check output of **ls** command.

Comment: Now the file is present. And `EDIT 5` part of question tells about dependency problem

Comment: Try this.. It solved similar issue *http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=104887*  **sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-i386 && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb**

Comment: Gained no success. I think something is broken in my case. Because I've installed in both 32-bit and 64-bit systems with no problem! I don't know know what the hell is wrong with this laptop

Answer (score 1):

Double click on the .deb file, `teamviewer_linux.deb` and wait to the Software Center opens. From there, you can install Teamviewer 9 without any problems.

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit part.

Comment: Try the 64 bit version.

Comment: The package I've downloaded is 32-Bit / 64-Bit Multiarch. As the site itself says. I Ubuntu 13.10 is multi-arch.

Comment: Yes I know. Do you have an oder version installed?

Comment: This was my first attempt to install teamviewer. It has been installed partially, so when I open teamviewer_linux.deb with Software Center I see repair command. Repairing the package didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [at this link](http://bramp.net/blog/2012/04/29/failed-ubuntu-update/). It may help.

Open the `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` log file in a text editor.
Locate any "broken" packages and remove them with `sudo apt-get remove <package>`.