# teamviewer 10, ubuntu 14.04 , connection problem

Tags: 14.04, wine, connection, teamviewer

here's my computer spec:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- 64 bit
- always do package updates everyday

I'm installing teamviewer 10 by using gdebi similar to this link: [team viewer error dependency install method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/installed-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error)

then there are many errors occur on log file, so I chmod all exe files in `/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin$` and hope it's ready for connection

but then I get something like this (on logfile, wine):

```
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"MountMgr" failed to start: 2
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"PlugPlay" failed to start: 2
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (3): stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x32f8e4 (nil)): stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000100, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32d510,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",0,0x32d858,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x32d510,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:resource:GetGuiResources (0xffffffff,0): stub
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)" 
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken QueryInformationToken( ..., TokenElevation, ...) semi-stub
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl discovery via DHCP not supported
fixme:bitmap:CreateBitmapIndirect planes = 0
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter 233 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter 4a 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter 407 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter 49 00000001
fixme:bitmap:CreateBitmapIndirect planes = 0
fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 0x1007a 0x00000000
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000122-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80040155
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {00000122-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}, 80040155
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c058 00000001
fixme:bitmap:CreateBitmapIndirect planes = 0
fixme:nls:GetGeoInfoW -1 4 0x32fc44 3 0
err:secur32:SECUR32_initSchannelSP TLS library not found, SSL connections will fail
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
```

it's still not ready for connection.

any idea how to solve this?

I've tried to uninstall and install it again using teamviewer 9, same problem occurs.

Comment: The problem here is *not* because of multiarch (the problem referenced in http://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/installed-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error. I have the same problem on a pure 32bit installation. I guess the important log line is: "TLS library not found, SSL connections will fail"

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question , Open your terminal and type or paste

```
sudo apt-get install winbind
```

then try to launch again.

Comment: it doesn't work.. there's no state change in teamviewer