# Install a package which is not in a repository

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, deb

I want to install teamviewer which offers a `.deb` package.
I read I can use `dpkg` and then do `apt-get install -f` to fix the dependencies. Or use `gdebi`.

Are those the best solutions?

Also I understand that in both cases, the package will not be automatically updated.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/installed-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error

Comment: Yes, right now manual installation is the best (and the only) way.

Answer (score 1):

Download [TeamViewer](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb) and save the .deb file.
Open the folder where you saved the file.

Click on the downloaded .deb file.
Ubuntu Software Center opens.
Now click on **Install** to start ...

All dependencies including the i386 (32 bit) packages needed will be installed automatically.
This is the recommended way ... as you can read in the [TeamViewer installation instructions](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx).
TeamViewer isn't available in any repository, to update it you have to repeat the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, those are the best (and AFAIK the only) ones.

I personally prefer using Terminal for this kind of stuff, but if you prefer a graphic interface, you can use `gdebi`, as you said, or the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter) (which I think is the default behavior if you double-click a `.deb` file in Ubuntu).

[These](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx) are the official TeamViewer's install instructions.

Also, keep in mind that in some cases [you could have problems](https://askubuntu.com/q/362951/477290installing) TeamViewer on Debian-based OS's, as **@TrungTran** mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

cd into the directory where the .deb file is. Or you can go to the directory using a GUI File Manager, open terminal there and write the following command:

> sudo dpkg -i package_name

To fix dependencies try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```