# how to install libsm6:i386 on 14.04 LTS 64bit?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, 32-bit, libraries

I tried to install teamviewer. so I followed the step in [Installed Teamviewer using a 64-bits system, but I get a dependency error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/installed-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error?newreg=db5348fd582a468aad80deaa45e5b41b).

However, I could not install libsm6:i386...

```
wooruang@wooruang-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install libsm6:i386  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have  
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable  
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created  
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:  

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
libsm6:i386 : Depends: libuuid1:i386 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

this is the result message.

so I tried to install libuuid1:i386, but it required another dependencies over and over again...

Could you please tell me what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try enabling the i386 architecture with this command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then update/upgrade packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and try to install libsm again.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. But I still have the problem.