# TeamViewer on AWS EC2 no connection

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, teamviewer

Trying to install TeamViewer on Ubuntu 14.04 AWS EC2 instance with K80 GPU. Currently I have ubuntu-desktop running and TightVNC working.

The TeamViewer tar version **works fine** (I can connect remotely using my ID and password), but the installed version keeps displaying `Not ready. Please check your connection`.

I tried:

- Rebooting
- Stopping and starting the daemon
- Installing with apt-get, gdebi, manually (basically everything from [Installed Teamviewer using a 64-bit system, but I get a dependency error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/installed-teamviewer-using-a-64-bit-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error))
- A bunch of other stuff...

I thought the problem has something to do with the framebuffer errors so I followed https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/Teamviewer-Host-EC2-Ubuntu-Server-The-framebuffer-console-seems/m-p/9964 but it didn't help.

Here's the TeamViewer log if that helps...

```
2017/07/31 20:23:15.075  4029 140044686686080 gX1   Logger started.
2017/07/31 20:23:15.076  4029 140044686686080 gX1   Found 0 Minidump files ...
2017/07/31 20:23:15.076  4029 140044686686080 gX1   Found 0 core dump files ...
2017/07/31 20:23:15.077  4029 140044686686080 gX1   systemd: logind service available
2017/07/31 20:23:15.078  4029 140044686686080 gX1   systemd: New seat seat0 [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0, activeSession='', canGraphical=1, canTTY=1, canMultiSession=1]
2017/07/31 20:23:15.082  4029 140044686686080 gX1   SystemdSessionInfo: New session SystemdSessionInfo [id=1 user=ubuntu state=user active=1 reliable=1 infoId=0] [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31 TTY= seat= display= vtnr=4294967295 owner=[SysUser_Lin: ubuntu [uid=1000, gid=1000 home=/home/ubuntu gecos=Ubuntu shell=/bin/bash]] idle=0(1501532593207174) active=1 type=tty class=user state=active timestamp=1501529883809932 service=sshd defaultCG=systemd:/user/1000.user/1.session leader=1849 audit=1 remote=1 rHost=bzq-109-66-122-182.red.bezeqint.net rUser= killProc=0]
2017/07/31 20:23:15.082  4029 140044686686080 gX1   SysSessionInfoManager: Session Information provided by systemd [priority: 0]
2017/07/31 20:23:15.082  4029 140044686686080 gX1   SysSessionInfoManager: Session Information provided by VT [priority: 2]
2017/07/31 20:23:15.082  4029 140044686686080 gX1   XSocket observer: watching /tmp/.X11-unix
2017/07/31 20:23:15.082  4029 140044686686080 gX1   XSocket observer: adding XSession: 1
2017/07/31 20:23:15.096  4029 140044686686080 gX1   FBSessionObserver: Framebuffer device /dev/fb0 has 24bit depth. Only 32bit and 16bit are supported.
2017/07/31 20:23:15.096  4029 140044686686080 gX1!  FrameBuffer: Cannot access /dev/fb0, frame buffer support unavailable
2017/07/31 20:23:15.097  4029 140044686686080 gX1!  XSession: Reading TTY from X-Server process failed.
2017/07/31 20:23:15.097  4029 140044686686080 gX1   XSession[1]: Retrieved XAuth from commandline
2017/07/31 20:23:15.098  4029 140044686686080 gX1!  VTSessionInfoProvider: Failed setting TTY for session 1 on display ':1'
2017/07/31 20:23:15.098  4029 140044686686080 gX1   SysSessionInfoManager: assigned session 1 to info provider 'None'
2017/07/31 20:23:15.100  4029 140044686686080 gX1!!!XFixes extension not found, Errorcode=11
2017/07/31 20:23:15.100  4029 140044686686080 gX1   TVGuiSlave.64: Running
2017/07/31 20:23:15.084  4030 4113991424 QX1   Logger started.
2017/07/31 20:23:15.085  4030 4113991424 QX1   Found 0 Minidump files ...
2017/07/31 20:23:15.085  4030 4113991424 QX1   Found 0 core dump files ...
2017/07/31 20:23:15.087  4030 4113991424 QX1   systemd: logind service available
2017/07/31 20:23:15.088  4030 4113991424 QX1   systemd: New seat seat0 [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0, activeSession='', canGraphical=1, canTTY=1, canMultiSession=1]
2017/07/31 20:23:15.091  4030 4113991424 QX1   SystemdSessionInfo: New session SystemdSessionInfo [id=1 user=ubuntu state=user active=1 reliable=1 infoId=0] [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31 TTY= seat= display= vtnr=4294967295 owner=[SysUser_Lin: ubuntu [uid=1000, gid=1000 home=/home/ubuntu gecos=Ubuntu shell=/bin/bash]] idle=0(1501532593207174) active=1 type=tty class=user state=active timestamp=1501529883809932 service=sshd defaultCG=systemd:/user/1000.user/1.session leader=1849 audit=1 remote=1 rHost=bzq-109-66-122-182.red.bezeqint.net rUser= killProc=0]
2017/07/31 20:23:15.091  4030 4113991424 QX1   SysSessionInfoManager: Session Information provided by systemd [priority: 0]
2017/07/31 20:23:15.092  4030 4113991424 QX1   SysSessionInfoManager: Session Information provided by VT [priority: 2]
2017/07/31 20:23:15.092  4030 4113991424 QX1   XSocket observer: watching /tmp/.X11-unix
2017/07/31 20:23:15.092  4030 4113991424 QX1   XSocket observer: adding XSession: 1
2017/07/31 20:23:15.106  4030 4113991424 QX1   FBSessionObserver: Framebuffer device /dev/fb0 has 24bit depth. Only 32bit and 16bit are supported.
2017/07/31 20:23:15.106  4030 4113991424 QX1!  FrameBuffer: Cannot access /dev/fb0, frame buffer support unavailable
2017/07/31 20:23:15.107  4030 4113991424 QX1!  XSession: Reading TTY from X-Server process failed.
2017/07/31 20:23:15.108  4030 4113991424 QX1   XSession[1]: Retrieved XAuth from commandline
2017/07/31 20:23:15.108  4030 4113991424 QX1!  VTSessionInfoProvider: Failed setting TTY for session 1 on display ':1'
2017/07/31 20:23:15.108  4030 4113991424 QX1   SysSessionInfoManager: assigned session 1 to info provider 'None'
2017/07/31 20:23:15.110  4030 4113991424 QX1   TVGuiDelegate: Running
2017/07/31 20:23:15.266  4029 140044497045248 gX1   Audio: PulseAudio enabled
2017/07/31 20:23:15.268  4029 140044482193152 gX1!! PulseAudio: Context failed: Connection refused, Errorcode=2
2017/07/31 20:23:15.268  4029 140044482193152 gX1!! PulseAudio: Unable to connect to server, no server running?, Errorcode=2
2017/07/31 20:23:15.268  4029 140044497045248 gX1!! Audio: Unable to initialise PulseAudio
2017/07/31 20:23:14.632     8    26 GX1   Logger started.
2017/07/31 20:23:14.656     8    26 GX1   StringCompare locale: English_United States.1252
2017/07/31 20:23:15.050     8    26 GX1!! SetProcessStartupOptions(): SetProcessDEPPolicy() failed! LE=120, Errorcode=87
2017/07/31 20:23:15.068     8    26 GX1   TVW X ErrorHandler org 7e88fb17, def 7e71f8f0 cur 7dd153eb
2017/07/31 20:23:15.072     8    26 GX1   Wine: Wine DLL initialized
2017/07/31 20:23:15.072     8    26 GX1   Wine: wine-1.6

2017/07/31 20:23:15.072     8    26 GX1   TVW SID0: SpawnSlave: pid 0
2017/07/31 20:23:15.072     8    26 GX1   TVW SID0: SpawnSlave: loading TVGuiSlave.64
2017/07/31 20:23:15.076     8    26 GX1   TVW ObserveFork: OK
2017/07/31 20:23:15.076     8    26 GX1   Wine: Spawned slave process with type 0
2017/07/31 20:23:15.077     8    26 GX1   TVW SID1: SpawnSlave: pid 0
2017/07/31 20:23:15.077     8    26 GX1   TVW SID1: SpawnSlave: loading TVGuiDelegate
2017/07/31 20:23:15.085     8    26 GX1   TVW ObserveFork: OK
2017/07/31 20:23:15.086     8    26 GX1   Wine: Spawned slave process with type 1
2017/07/31 20:23:15.087     8    26 GX1   Starting GUI master for slave type 0
2017/07/31 20:23:15.100     8    26 GX1   Slave connected to GUI master
2017/07/31 20:23:15.101     8    26 GX1   Starting GUI master for slave type 1
2017/07/31 20:23:15.111     8    26 GX1   Slave connected to GUI master
2017/07/31 20:23:15.139     8    26 GX1   Monitors: X11 Windowing System, \\.\DISPLAY1, 1024x768 (0,0), flags=21, dpi=96
2017/07/31 20:23:15.164     8    26 GX1   CMain::LoadResourceDLLs(): No custom resource dll found
2017/07/31 20:23:15.164     8    26 GX1   InterProcessBase::SecureNetwork created
2017/07/31 20:23:15.171     8    26 GX1   AutoLogin::Login: enabled: 1



Start:              2017/07/31 20:23:15.171 (UTC)
Version:            12.0.76279 
ID:                 0
Loglevel:           LogAll (0)
License:            0
Server:             master5.teamviewer.com
IC:                 0
CPU:                x86 Family 6 Model 79 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
CPU extensions:     h9
OS:                 Lx Ubuntu 14.04.5 LT (32-bit)
IP:                 172.31.48.116
Proxy-Settings:     Type=0 IP= User=
AppPath:            C:\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe
UserAccount:        ubuntu

2017/07/31 20:23:15.176     8    26 GX1   Win32_GUI::FontReallyExists: 'Segoe UI' found 0 matches.
2017/07/31 20:23:15.176     8    26 GX1   Win32_GUI::FontReallyExists: 'Liberation Sans' found 4 matches.
2017/07/31 20:23:15.182     8    26 GX1   InterProcessBase::StartTcpCommunicationInternal(): setting m_NetworkConnector to new TCP connector
2017/07/31 20:23:15.182     8    26 GX1   Opening local TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:5939
2017/07/31 20:23:15.182     8    26 GX1   Local TCP connection established
2017/07/31 20:23:15.183     8    26 GX1   Process ID:  L 3889 /  W 8
2017/07/31 20:23:15.264     8    26 GX1   SettingsIPCReception receive a SYNCHRONISE Settings command : UserSettings
2017/07/31 20:23:15.264     8    26 GX1   Received Control_InitIPC_Response processtype=1
2017/07/31 20:23:15.265     8    26 GX1   Received Control_InitIPC_Response runningProcesses=3
2017/07/31 20:23:15.265     8    26 GX1   Control_InitIPC_Response: all processes 3 completely initialized
2017/07/31 20:23:15.271     8    26 GX1   Slave signalized initialization
2017/07/31 20:23:15.300     8    31 GX1   ProxySearch: no PAC script detected via WPAD
2017/07/31 20:23:15.303     8    31 GX1   ProxySearch: no PAC script detected via WPAD
rent session available (yet)
2017/07/31 20:23:15.358     8    28 GX1   Slave signalized initialization
2017/07/31 20:23:15.359     8     9 GX1   tvshared::WindowsSessionStateManager::WindowsSessionStateManager(0232F338) state 0
2017/07/31 20:23:15.359     8     9 GX1   VoIP: VoIPCentral: Set capturing-device = "", rendering-device = ""
2017/07/31 20:23:15.360  4029 140044473800448 gX1!! PulseAudio: Context failed: Connection refused, Errorcode=2
2017/07/31 20:23:15.360  4029 140044473800448 gX1!! PulseAudio: Unable to connect to server, no server running?, Errorcode=2
2017/07/31 20:23:15.360  4029 140044497045248 gX1   ALSA: No cards of type 0 found
2017/07/31 20:23:15.360  4029 140044497045248 gX1   ALSA: No cards of type 1 found
2017/07/31 20:23:15.361     8     9 GX1   MachineID m=1 - 1
2017/07/31 20:23:15.362     8     9 GX1   TVUpdate::Init() Version-URL: download.teamviewer.com/download/update/ Update-URL: download.teamviewer.com/download/update/
2017/07/31 20:23:15.364     8     9 GX1   TVUpdate::Init() Preview Channel Number : 1
2017/07/31 20:23:15.366     8     9 GX1   DynamicPasswordUIModel::ShouldShowDynamicPassword(): dynPw=1 allowIncoming=1 id=0 ka=0 lanAllowed=0 lanOnly=0 networkState=1 showDynPwd=0
2017/07/31 20:23:15.369     8     9 GX1!! MachineHooks: Library not found, Errorcode=126
2017/07/31 20:23:15.447     8     9 GX1   Wine: HwndToWindow 00010058 -> 2600002
2017/07/31 20:23:15.447     8     9 GX1   ManagerHolderStateMachine: Switching from None to NotReady
2017/07/31 20:23:15.447     8    23 GX1   ChatManager::ChatManager: created
2017/07/31 20:23:15.447     8    23 GX1   ChatManager::Factory: ChatManager created
2017/07/31 20:23:15.448     8    23 GX1   IncomingBetterChatCommandHandler::IncomingBetterChatCommandHandler: created
2017/07/31 20:23:15.448     8     9 GX1!! DragDropRegistration: could not register window, HR=80040155
2017/07/31 20:23:15.448     8    23 GX1   IncomingChatCommandRegistration::Start: registering for ready state properties
2017/07/31 20:23:15.450     8     9 GX1   AccountLoginGUI::CreateLoginKey(): [OnlineState] System is set to Visible.
2017/07/31 20:23:15.473     8     9 GX1   Wine: HwndToWindow 00010058 -> 2600002
2017/07/31 20:23:15.473     8     9 GX1   Wine: HwndToWindow 000100C6 -> 2600005
2017/07/31 20:23:15.476     8     9 GX1   CMainWindow::ShouldShowDynamicPassword(): dynPw=1 allowIncoming=1 id=0 ka=0 lanAllowed=0 lanOnly=0 networkState=1 showDynPwd=0
2017/07/31 20:23:15.478     8     9 GX1!! ServerControl: RegisterPowerSettingNotification failed with error 0
2017/07/31 20:23:15.510  4029 140044473800448 gX1!! PulseAudio: Context failed: Connection refused, Errorcode=2
2017/07/31 20:23:15.510  4029 140044473800448 gX1!! PulseAudio: Unable to connect to server, no server running?, Errorcode=2
2017/07/31 20:23:15.511  4029 140044497045248 gX1   ALSA: No cards of type 0 found
2017/07/31 20:23:15.511  4029 140044497045248 gX1   ALSA: No cards of type 1 found
2017/07/31 20:23:15.513  4029 140044497045248 gX1!! ALSAMixer: Unable to attach mixer to device default (No such file or directory) [Master] on default, Errorcode=2
2017/07/31 20:23:15.513  4029 140044497045248 gX1!! ALSAMixer: Unable to attach mixer to device default (No such file or directory) [Capture] on default, Errorcode=2
2017/07/31 20:23:15.513     8    33 GX1!! WineMixer: Unable to initialise mixer -1 -1
2017/07/31 20:23:15.514     8    33 GX1   VoIP: VoIPCentral: Set capturing-device = "", rendering-device = ""
2017/07/31 20:23:15.556     8     9 GX1!! TVW Wine: SetWindowManagerClassHint: No such window
2017/07/31 20:23:15.556     8     9 GX1!! TVW Wine: SetWindowManagerClassHint: No such window
2017/07/31 20:23:25.319  4030 4030724928 QX1!  SessionBusWatcher: no suitable session bus found
```